# FreePBX UK Dial Patterns Route Through Specific Trunk

Tags: asterisk, voip, freepbx

I've read a ton of links and tutorials and for some reason cannot get my dial patterns to work correctly.
I've got Freepbx installed and working properly - no issue there.

I want to create a dial pattern that identifies a number and routes it trough a specific outbound trunk without the use of a prefix.

So for example, I have 3 outbound routes and 3 different trunks, one for mobiles, one for landlines and one for international calls.

If a number starts with 07 it should go through route 1/trunk1.
If a number starts with 020 it should go through route 2/trunk2.
If a number starts with 001 it should go through route 3/trunk3.

Is this possible?

Comment: When you dial a number that starts with 07, should the call include the initial 0 or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Let's presume your outgoing context is called `outgoing` and your SIP providers are named `trunk1`, `trunk2` and `trunk3` and are already properly configured.  Your code would look something like this:

```
[outgoing]
exten => _07XXX.,1,Verbose(2, Call via Trunk 1 Provider for ${EXTEN})
 same => n, Dial(SIP/trunk1/${EXTEN})

exten => _020XXX.,1,Verbose(2, Call via Trunk 2 Provider for ${EXTEN})
 same => n, Dial(SIP/trunk2/${EXTEN})

exten => _001XXX.,1,Verbose(2, Call via Trunk 3 Provider for ${EXTEN})
 same => n, Dial(SIP/trunk3/${EXTEN})
```

**Further Reading:**

- https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching
- http://the-asterisk-book.com/1.6/einleitung-regex.html